# How to measure time elapsed from full hour?

Tags: python, time

I'm looking for a way to count time difference between current time and last full hour. (e.g it's 11:31 now so it's 00:31 from 11:00) `time.strftime('%H:00:00')` returns string `11:00:00` but Im totally clueless what to do next.

Comment: have a look at `time.localtime()`

Comment: What I did when I needed full x minutes (in my case it was 10 or 15, so yours is easier): get current datetime (`datime.now()`), then make a second one with correct minutes and seconds (in your case: just 0s). Then you can subtract both and get timedelta object. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
time.strftime('%M:00')
```

You want to get the minutes and don't care about the hours. So just format the minutes as output. Or perhaps you want to get the minutes from a `datetime` object as number:

```
m = datetime.now().minute
```